# Do broken backlinks from HTTP websites matter or does Google only count HTTPS links now?

Tags: google, https, backlinks

Some pages have been removed not redirected from the website of a client and now there are some broken backlinks but mainly coming from websites that are HTTP (have not migrated to HTTPS).

How does Google treat backlinks from HTTP websites? Do they still affect ranking? Should I try to fix these or not bother?

Comment: "Should I try to fix these...?" - How would you intend to "fix" these URLs if the target page has been "removed"?

Comment: Well the information is not gone the url has just changed so I can still work around to redirect them if I know the target link which I do. But like I said they are mostly from HTTP websites so I want to know if it is even worth it to go through all that.

Answer (score 1):

Google uses HTTP or HTTPS as one of over 200 signals used in the ranking process for a web page. Sites with HTTPS do rank somewhat higher than HTTP sites do however it is a relatively low level signal as opposed to other higher ranking signals. In addition what matters for your site is the validity of the backlinks and your site being HTTPS. If these links where at one point valid and lead to valuable content then I would recommend putting in 301 redirects for all of these links to redirect the connection from the HTTP version of the pages to the HTTPS version of the pages.